# About character comparision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to the route i type in in the address blank localhost:3000/ff00ff

here 'ff00ff', it should be like a hex code,
if it is, reply Hello world,'ff00ff'!
if it isn't, reply 404 not found.

but the problem is, it doesn't work. Hint:"Error: Uncaught error: reply interface called twice"

Here's the code i wrote

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{name}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        var judge = new String(request.params.name);
        console.log(judge);
        for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        if (judge[i]==='0'||'1'||'2'||'3'||'4'||'5'||'6'||'7'||'8'||'9'||'a'||'b'||'c'||'d'||'e'||'f'||'A'||'B'||'C'||'D'||'E'||'F'){
             reply('Hello, ' + judge + '!')
           }
        else{
              reply('404 Page Not Found')
            }   
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: You are calling `reply` within your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison is attempting to OR all the characters together, which JavaScript will simply evaluate to `'0'`, thus yielding `false` on `judge[i]==='0'` for all non-zero characters.

For comparisons, you'll have to do each comparison separately. i.e.:

```
if (judge[i] === '0' || judge[i] === '1' || ...) { // ...
```

**However**, there is a far easier way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Enter RegExp and the `String.match` function.

```
if (judge.match(/^[A-F0-9]{6}$/i)) { // ...
```

This checks that `judge` is a 6-character long string containing only A-F (or a-f) and 0-9.

Comment: So it does. Edited accordingly.

Comment: *"thus yielding false on judge[i]===true"* - Except it isn't comparing `judge[i]` to the result of all of the `||` operations, because `===` has a higher operator precedence than `||`: it does `judge[i] === "0"` first, then applies the `||` so the whole expression evaluates to either `true` or `'1'`. (Of course, it doesn't produce the desired result either way.)

Comment: While it makes sense, wouldn't that cause the whole statement to evaluate to `true` (since `'1'` is truthy)? According to the original question, it's yielding `false`.

Comment: Yes, it won't evaluate anything after the `1`. The whole statement evaluates to either `true` or `'1'` depending on the value of `judge[i]`, and either way that is truthy. The question doesn't say it is yielding `false`. The OP is calling `reply()` inside the `if` on every iteration, hence the reported error message.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand in what case the statement evaluates to `'1'`, wouldnt it always be just `true`

Comment: @vinayakj It would evaluate to `1` any time that `judge[i]` is not `'0'`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I actually didn't notice that before (properly indent your code kids!) and the regex solution fixed the problem without me noticing, nice catch.
@vinayakj It would, we're referring to `'1'` being the next thing JS "sees" during evaluation of that statement, assuming `judge[i]` is non-zero.

Comment: thanks guys got it. `false(y) || '1'  gives '1'`.
I was still evaluating right to left(OR operations first), But as nnnnnn said `===` has higher precedence than `||`, that makes sense and Just remembered the trick we use to initialize variables without using if.